# Tri-State Checkbox in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, treeview

I am developing a macro in Excel VBA and I am not expert. I need to show data in Treeview. In tree view there are only two state for checkbox. Either select or not select. I want to know is there any way(Preferably simple way) to show a third state.

Let say I have 10 children in a node, If user select checkbox for 5 children then parent node should display partial selection state of check box.

It is not needed to be a checkbox any control that show tristate would be fine.

Note: Before I came here I spent more than 5 hours in google. But I am not able find solution that match my need.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: No, the treeview does not support tristate checkboxes.  Consider using 3 different images for each node to indicate state

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23733375/is-it-possible-to-simulate-tri-state-checkboxes-in-microsoft-treeview-control-6